# Connectivity error for Azure DevOps agent connecting to SQL VM databases via PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, azure-devops, devops

I'm trying to set up Azure DevOps to run PowerShell scripts against SQL Server databases hosted on a VM.  The script (at present) is a simple backup script for testing purposes and runs without issue via PowerShell ISE on the VM:

```
$userName = "MyCompany-SqlServer\DevOps"
$password = "*****"
$serverInstance = "MyCompany-Sql"
$database = "MyCompanyDatabase"
$backupFilePath = "S:\DevOpsBackups"
$fileDate = $(Get-Date -format 'yyyyMMdd')
$backupFile = "$backupFilePath\$database-$fileDate.bak"
$pWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $userName, $pWord
cls
Write-Host Backing up $database
Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance $serverInstance  -Database $database  -BackupFile $backupFile -CopyOnly -CompressionOption On -SqlCredential $credential
```

When run via DevOps on a release pipeline task it fails with:

```
2023-03-20T13:33:33.7640125Z Backing up MyCompanyDatabase
2023-03-20T13:34:14.4239350Z ##[error]Backup-SqlDatabase : Failed to connect to server MyCompany-Sql.
At D:\a\_temp\46e76f20-b9b4-4643-8a6e-07cbc8498baa.ps1:29 char:1
+ Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance $serverInstance  -Database $databa ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Backup-SqlDatabase], ConnectionFailureException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionFailureException,Microsoft.SqlServer.Man 
   agement.PowerShell.BackupSqlDatabaseCommand
2023-03-20T13:34:14.4815400Z ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
2023-03-20T13:34:14.5311388Z ##[section]Finishing: PowerShell Script
```

Reading into other peoples' experiences, I have tried the following approaches to no avail:

1. Run the script using my own login credentials (server/SQL admin)
2. Substituted the login account with the SQL Server `sa` credentials
3. Created a Windows login then a new SQL Server login mapped to that

I assumed this must be a SQL Server permissions issue, but because the script runs fine within PS ISE, I'm totally confused as to what the underlying issue actually is.

### Update

Responding to comments, running `Test-NetConnection` fails with (server name substituted):

```
2023-03-21T11:09:38.6985316Z Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
2023-03-21T11:09:38.7018451Z --     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------                  
2023-03-21T11:09:38.7035965Z 1      a79e797f-2d5...                 NotStarted    False                                ...                      
2023-03-21T11:09:41.7367105Z WARNING: Name resolution of MyCompany-Sql failed
2023-03-21T11:09:41.7705121Z 
2023-03-21T11:09:41.7765631Z ComputerName             : MyCompany-Sql
2023-03-21T11:09:41.7784973Z RemoteAddress            : 
2023-03-21T11:09:41.7802978Z ResolvedAddresses        : 
2023-03-21T11:09:41.7874016Z PingSucceeded            : False
2023-03-21T11:09:41.7910331Z PingReplyDetails         : 
2023-03-21T11:09:41.7911650Z TcpClientSocket          : 
2023-03-21T11:09:41.7980940Z TcpTestSucceeded         : False
2023-03-21T11:09:41.7999683Z RemotePort               : 0
2023-03-21T11:09:41.8021003Z TraceRoute               : 
2023-03-21T11:09:41.8038092Z Detailed                 : False
2023-03-21T11:09:41.8055751Z InterfaceAlias           : 
2023-03-21T11:09:41.8127030Z InterfaceIndex           : 0
2023-03-21T11:09:41.8147624Z InterfaceDescription     : 
2023-03-21T11:09:41.8207864Z NetAdapter               : 
2023-03-21T11:09:41.8208865Z NetRoute                 : 
2023-03-21T11:09:41.8210513Z SourceAddress            : 
2023-03-21T11:09:41.8212980Z NameResolutionSucceeded  : False
2023-03-21T11:09:41.8234948Z BasicNameResolution      : 
2023-03-21T11:09:41.8252474Z LLMNRNetbiosRecords      : 
2023-03-21T11:09:41.8270502Z DNSOnlyRecords           : 
2023-03-21T11:09:41.8295866Z AllNameResolutionResults : 
2023-03-21T11:09:41.8365320Z IsAdmin                  : False
2023-03-21T11:09:41.8367615Z NetworkIsolationContext  : 
2023-03-21T11:09:41.8372941Z MatchingIPsecRules       : 
2023-03-21T11:09:41.8379585Z 
2023-03-21T11:09:41.8454408Z ##[warning]Name resolution of MyCompany-Sql failed
```

But checking Windows Server, that name is definitely correct:

[image]

Comment: Connect to database using SQL Server management Studio and check log files with the explorer under management. See what user and group were used at time of failure and compare with a good connection.  Most likely the user/group is different.  Most windows networks will not allow a connection with username and password and require a credential.  Sometimes username/password will work locally but not on a remote machine.  When logging in with SSMS the login windows will show the server\instance and the Credentials (Windows or SQL).  There should be the same on you application.

Comment: Firewall rules? If it's a default instance (i.e.: named `MSSQLSERVER`) then it's probably listening on tcp/1433 and that access is needed through any intermediate firewalls. What's the output of `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName "MyCompany-Sql" -Port 1433`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning is that to be run on DevOps or via Powershell on the VM?  The DevOps agent is registered on the VM so I can't see how the firewall could interfere...

Comment: `Test-NetConnection` is a PowerShell cmdlet. Run it within a pipeline `script` block to ensure that the DevOps agent has the required access. DevOps self-hosted Windows agents are still computer programs running on your Windows computer and so are still subject to all the same software firewall rules as all your other Windows software. Check if you have egress rules enabled on the Windows host running the  agent, likewise check if you have ingress rules enabled on the Windows host running the SQL Server service. (These may or may not be the same host.)

Comment: @jdweng The log files show absolutely nothing related.  Username/password of the server admin (full rights to absolutely everything) have also been used and the error still persists.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning updating the question now with results.  DNS lookup failed.

Comment: Did you run PS by right click shortcut and select Run As Admin?  Are the log files showing same time as when failed on PS?  If there is no log entry at time of failure you never attempted to connect to database.  Make sure the connection string shows same server as in the login for SSMS.  If still not seeing entries in log files than TLS is failing and there is a certificate issue. or Port number is wrong.

Comment: @jdweng yes I agree; I don't think the server (VM) connection is ever being made.  @AlwaysLearning appears to be onto something with the `Test-NetConnection` approach.  It's a mystery to me because I though the local hosted agent on the actual VM was processing these requests so all settings would be local to that...?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning regarding ingress/egress rules, are those rules defined in the documentation anywhere so that I can cross-check?  This is a database server on a private VLAN to keep it away from public access but I'm not sure what the rules are to apply.

Comment: Test-Net Connection is doing a ping.  If ping fails there is no route between client and server.  If ping works than issue is a port connection.  Ping does not use Port.  Ping is not blocked by firewall, but will only work inside same network(domain) where there is a route.  This is not a powershell issue.  It is an IP routing issue.

Comment: If the DevOps agent is on the same Windows host as the SQL Server you'll be wanting to look at the egress/ingress rules defined in "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security." But if `Test-NetConnection` can't resolve your server name then perhaps the Windows host doesn't actually know itself by that name... have you tried using its local network IP address instead? i.e.: what addresses are shown by `ipconfig /all`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning `ipconfig` only shows the "internal" VNET IP address; there is no external IP or DNS name.  Therefore it must be an Azure NSG rule that needs opening.  I've just stumbled upon *Microsoft's Allowed IP addresses and domain URLs* (shorturl.at/bpy89) reading material which I believe I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would've normally deleted this question as the solution was based on initial user error, but I want to share my findings as its taken over a week to get clarity on this and Microsoft's naming conventions are far from intuitive (IMHO).

*Aside, I am very grateful for the comments posted above, as these helped to provide clarity on the underlying approach to solving this.*

If the DevOps agent is hosted on your VM within your Azure infrastructure, and you want it to execute scripts against SQL Server installed on that VM, then the **Group Job Type** should be **Deployment Group Job**:

[image]

Originally I had chosen **Agent Job** because there is an agent that runs on the VM.

Once selected, you can then configure the job to run against the VM you (have already) created as a deployment group target:

[image: deployment job]

You then select the simple **PowerShell Script** task and populate it to target the SQL Server instance.  Note the naming conventions and lack of credentials because the agent runs as `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` (something I'm also now investigating further):

[image]